# Regular Expression - Match Email Address with Exceptions

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

Please read the question carefully, it's not about validating email addresses!

I'm trying to construct a regular expression (currently in C#) that extracts all email addresses from a text, with two specific exceptions.

I got:

- user1@company.com
- user2@company.com
- user3@company.com
- user1@private.com
- user2@private.com

all in the same text file on the same line, delimited by whitespace character.

At first I tried to match all of these email addresses except the ones starting with "user1". I used:

```
[\S]*(?<!user1)@[\S]*\..[a-zA-Z.]{1,}
```

which works well. Now I have another requirement that sais: Also do not match if the complete email address matches "user2@private.com". So it should match "user2@company.com", therefore I can't use:

```
[\S]*(?<!(user1|user2))@[\S]*\..[a-zA-Z.]{1,}
```

Therefore I tried an additional negative lookbehind:

```
([\S]*(?<!user1)@[\S]*\..[a-zA-Z.]{1,})(?<!user2@private\.com)
```

which doesn't work because it seems to be satisfied with matching "user2@private.co" I guess. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? My head already hurts,...

I would use additional code, but as I'm using a third party software that only gives me the option of Regular Expression, and only the option of a single regular expression, that's all I've got,...

Comment: Maybe [this approach](http://ideone.com/zwEA2C) will work for you. Split with whitespace, get the items matching `@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"` and use a bit of code to filter out unwanted matches.

Comment: A single regex solution - [`(?<!\S)(?!user1@|user2@private\.com(?!\S))\S+@\S+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?!\S)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%3f!user1%40%7cuser2%40private.com%28%3f!%5cS%29%29%5cS%2b%40%5cS%2b%5c.%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=user1%40company.com++user2%40company.com++user3%40company.com+%0d%0a+user1%40private.com+user2%40private.com), but it does not look nice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very nice,...you want to add that as answer? I will have to take some time to understand what you've done though,...but I see it works.

Comment: I will post both solutions.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Please read the post again, it's not a duplicate of what you have posted. It's not about validating regular email addresses.

Comment: It is not about validating an email, it is about extracting email-like substrings with exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single regex solution that does not look nice is

```
(?<!\S)(?!user1@|user2@private\.com(?!\S))\S+@\S+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CS%29%28%3F!user1%40%7Cuser2%40private%5C.com%28%3F!%5CS%29%29%5CS%2B%40%5CS%2B%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D%28%3F!%5CS%29&i=user1%40company.com%20%20user2%40company.com%20%20user3%40company.com%20%0D%0A%20user1%40private.com%20user2%40private.com).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)`  - a position not preceded with a non-whitespace char
- `(?!user1@|user2@private\.com(?!\S))` - that position cannot be followed with `user1@` or `user2@private.com` not followed with a non-whitespace char
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace
- `@` - a literal `@`
- `\S+`  - 1+ non-whitespace
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?!\S)` - 2 or more ASCII letters not followed with a non-whitespace char.

A more readable approach is to split with whitespace, get the items matching `@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"` and use a bit of code to filter out unwanted matches:

```
var s = @"Text user1@company.com here user2@company.com and user3@company.com here user1@private.com more user2@private.com";
var result = s.Split().Where(m => 
        Regex.IsMatch(m, @"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$") && m != "user2@private.com" && !m.StartsWith("user1@"));
foreach (var str in result)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
// => user2@company.com, user3@company.com
```

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/zwEA2C).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a negative look ahead instead. The following solution should work if you have explicit emails you need to filter out. But keep in mind that it isn't exactly scalable. You would not want to have thousands of emails applied here.

`^(?!user1|user2(?!@company.com))[\S]*@[\S]*\..[a-zA-Z.]{1,}`

If you suspect that many of these rules could be applied at a future date then you might need to think about a better approach. If the emails to be filtered out are explicit (not patterns) then you could maintain a blacklist somewhere and filter them out after you have extracted/validated email address patterns.

Comment: Your regex will match 'user1@company.com', but I need it not to match. It should exclude "user1@<whatsoever>", but only "user2@private.com", but not "user2@company.com"...

Comment: @inzanez thaks for the clarification. I've updated the expression to reflect the need for the regex to ignore any address that begins with `user1` and any address that begins with `user2` but still match address that start `user2@company.com`. Let me know if this is suitable.

Comment: I changed it slightly so that splitting works finally: (?<!\S)(?!user1|user2(?!@company.com))[\S]*@[\S]*\..[a-zA-Z.]{1,}(?!\S)
Thank you for the nice alternative